# Should we first remove the unwanted independent variable or split the data into test train data?

Tags: machine-learning, preprocessing, missing-data

I wanted to know if we are dropping any independent variable as it has too many missing values(~75% or more) from the data then should we do it before splitting the data or after splitting the data

Answer (score 1):

**Whether it's removed before/after splitting** doesn't matter: the variable will not appear in any part of the data so it cannot cause any data leakage anyway.

However what might matter (at least in theory) is **from investigating which part of the data** was the decision made. Any preprocessing and design decision should be made based on the training set only in order to avoid any risk of data leakage (see [example](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/68768/64377)). In practice it's not really a problem in the case you mention.